# How do I pass a parameter from the mysql library in python to a stored procedure

Tags: python, mysql

This is my sql stored procedure

I want to check if the column that i pass from my python script not exist, if not exist, then created it.

```
            CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `columnas_fundamental`(
            IN nombre_columna VARCHAR(60)
            )
            BEGIN
            -- veo si la columna existe
            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 COLUMN_NAME  
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                        WHERE table_schema = 'fundamental_anual_data'
                        AND table_name = 'fundamental'
                        AND column_name = nombre_columna)
                         
            -- Si existe me retorna un valor (1), sino, la creo yo
            THEN
               -- hacer alguna acción, es decir, ALTER TABLE si faltan algunas columnas
               ALTER TABLE fundamental ADD COLUMN nombre_columna VARCHAR(60);
            
            END IF;
            END
            
            My python code is it:
```

This method api_data(data=data, ticker=ticker) in ticker recive a list of ticker like ['AAPL', 'MSFT',...] for each ticker we have same columns and sometime a column is different

```
            def fundamental():
                global id
                MysQl.select_db_type('localhost')
                start_time = time.time()
                banderin = False
                for ticker in tickers:
                    logger.notify(ticker)
                    for i in api_data(data=data, ticker=ticker):
                        for key, value in i.items():
                            if 'id' in key:
                                if not banderin:
                                    id = replace_str(value)
                                    # MysQl.alter_table_str(id)
                                    col = MysQl.cursor.callproc('columnas_fundamental', [id,])
                                    logger.notify(col)
            
                            else:
                                MysQl.insert_update_table(column_name=id, date=key, symbol=ticker, value=value)
            
                    banderin = True
                    continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments go as tuple not arrays

See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-callproc.html)

```
col = MysQl.cursor.callproc('columnas_fundamental', (id,))
```

for every argument in the stored procedure, there must be one in the tuple.

You have to rewrite your procedure Mysql doesn't like variables for cololmn names

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF exists column_fundamental;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `columnas_fundamental`(
IN _nombre_columna VARCHAR(60)
)
BEGIN
    -- veo si la columna existe
    -- veo si la columna existe
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE table_schema = 'fundamental_anual_data'
                AND table_name = 'fundamental'
                AND column_name = _nombre_columna)
                 
    -- Si existe me retorna un valor (1), sino, la creo yo
    THEN
           -- hacer alguna acción, es decir, ALTER TABLE si faltan algunas columnas

           SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE fundamental ADD COLUMN ',_nombre_columna,' VARCHAR(60);');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;            
    END IF;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I did it, but it didn't work either, it creates the column "column_name" which is my input variable of the stored procedure

Comment: please chaeck what is in **value**. i think you will find it is `column_name`

Comment: "value" comes with things that will give me an error in sql, the "replace_str" method makes replace of those things and returns that id which is how I need the column to pass it to the stored procedure

Comment: ^please debug it corectly id before and after you are using functions that i don't know and can't find in the official documentation, if your stored procedure make a column column_name, so it gets from python this in `id`, the rest as i already said you are the only one that can debug it.

Comment: The proble is that "nombre_columna" variable in sql, i think don´t be decalred or i don´t know whats happend because created the "nombre_columna" always and don´t get my colum name from python script

Comment: i will check the procedure

Comment: @Jaikoos the problem was in the procedure, i rewrote it

Comment: Can you tell me what´s the best way?

Comment: use the the procedure that i posted in my answer, it works now fine and of course the python code